# creating list of lists alimented with data from database gives empty list

Tags: django, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to plot a graph that shows the average call duration every day each minute for 7 days in the same plot, now I'm defining the function that will give me the data asked according to conditions which will be plotted but I'm always getting a list of empty lists.can any  one help me tof ind the bug? (acc is just an example of data from the global database)
This is the function:

```
import time
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import repeat
acc=[{u'switch_id': 3, u'hangup_cause_id': 7, u'start_uepoch': datetime(2015, 5, 8, 13, 32, 1), u'duration': 32}, {u'switch_id': 3, u'hangup_cause_id': 10, u'start_uepoch': datetime(2015, 5, 8, 13, 32, 8), u'duration': 20}, {u'switch_id': 3, u'hangup_cause_id': 10, u'start_uepoch': datetime(2015, 5, 8, 13, 32, 10), u'duration': 17}]
t = datetime.now()
y = t.year
m = t.month
d = t.day
donnees=[]
for k in range(7):
    try:
        m = t.month
        data=[]
        liste=[]
        liste_time=[]
        for i in acc:
            if (i["start_uepoch"].year == y and i["start_uepoch"].month == m and i["start_uepoch"].day == d-k):
            liste.append([i["start_uepoch"],i["duration"]])
        for q in range(24):
            for mnt in range(60):
                liste2=[]
                ACD=0
                somme_duration=0
                n=0
                for p in liste:
                    if (p[0].hour==q and p[0].minute == mnt):
                        liste2.append(p[1])
                        temps=p[0]
                if len(liste2)!=0:
                    for j in liste2:
                        somme_duration+=j
                        n+=1
                    ACD=round((float(somme_duration)/n)*100)/100
                    liste_time.append(calendar.timegm(temps.timetuple()))
                    data.append(ACD)                               
                else:
                    liste_time.append(calendar.timegm(temps.timetuple()))
                    data.append(0)
    except:
        pass
    donnees.append(data)
print donnees
```

Comment: Well clearly there's a bug, but you have *carefully hidden that bug* by putting `except: pass`. So we'll never know what it is. Remove that except clause and then you will see what the bug actually is.

Comment: ok I'll do and tell you

Comment: well the problem was the "temps" item in the last else block which can not be read so I replace it with q, now it's giving a list of zero...

Comment: now it's working! thanx any way your suggestion gives me the light to see the solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your try / except condition, if you remove it by settings `temps = None` after your loop it solves you issue :

```
import time
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import repeat
acc=[{u'switch_id': 3, u'hangup_cause_id': 7, u'start_uepoch': datetime(2015, 5, 8, 13, 32, 1), u'duration': 32}, {u'switch_id': 3, u'hangup_cause_id': 10, u'start_uepoch': datetime(2015, 5, 8, 13, 32, 8), u'duration': 20}, {u'switch_id': 3, u'hangup_cause_id': 10, u'start_uepoch': datetime(2015, 5, 8, 13, 32, 10), u'duration': 17}]
t = datetime.now()
y = t.year
m = t.month
d = t.day
donnees=[]
for k in range(7):
    m = t.month
    data=[]
    liste=[]
    liste_time=[]
    for i in acc:
        if (i["start_uepoch"].year == y and i["start_uepoch"].month == m and i["start_uepoch"].day == d-k):
            liste.append([i["start_uepoch"],i["duration"]])
    for q in range(24):
        for mnt in range(60):
            temps = None
            liste2=[]
            ACD=0
            somme_duration=0
            n=0
            for p in liste:
                if (p[0].hour==q and p[0].minute == mnt):
                    liste2.append(p[1])
                    temps=p[0]
            if temps:
                if len(liste2)!=0:
                    for j in liste2:
                        somme_duration+=j
                        n+=1
                    ACD=round((float(somme_duration)/n)*100)/100
                    liste_time.append(calendar.timegm(temps.timetuple()))
                    data.append(ACD)                               
                else:
                    liste_time.append(calendar.timegm(temps.timetuple()))
                    data.append(0)
    donnees.append(data)
print donnees
```

Comment: You are welcome. I believe your code could be optimized and I would be pleased to help you.